# Standard Heats and Free Energies of Formation and Absolute Entropies of 2-Chloro-2-methylpropane

Tags: thermodynamics, reference-request

Does 2-Chloro-2-methylpropane have standard heats and free energies of formation and absolute entropies values in a liquid state? 
http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/thermodynamic-data 
This website only provides the values in gaseous state and I can't seem to find the values for the liquid state anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: Maybe you somewhere find a copy of [CRC Handbook of Thermophysical and Thermochemical Data](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=3iIY7_i_A2kC) to have a look inside, if they have any values.

Answer (score 2):

$\Delta H_\mathrm{f}^\circ = -211.3~\mathrm{kJmol^{-1}}$

Neither source provided entropy or free energy data though but this is a start.

http://courses.chem.indiana.edu/c360/documents/thermodynamicdata.pdf
    http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C507200&Units=SI&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed

Comment: Couldn't you calculate those values using Hess's Law and the law related to free energy?